# Unzip 40k+ .gz files using terminal

Tags: bash, shell, gunzip

I have downloaded log files from a GCP bucket, that I need to parse in a later task. But for now, the files are compressed and are over 40k `.gz` files. I tried few commands and none of them worked:

```
find . -prune -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip {} +

find . -type f -exec gunzip {} +
```

Any idea how I can unzip that number of files using the cmd, I am using Bash on Mac.

Comment: You have almost done it. Just drop the `-prune`: `find . -name '*.gz' -exec gunzip {} +`

Comment: @JamesRisner the comment to this question was the answer to my problem. But thank you for answering anyways

Answer (score 0):

An optimization you can do is to allow more than one file per gunzip:

```
find . -type f -name \*.gz -print0 | xargs -0 gunzip
```

- This scans all directories from the current directory and below.
- locating all regular files (-type f) with a .gz file name ending.
- Piping the output to another command (xargs) null (\0) terminated.
- The xargs reads null terminate input (-0).
- The calling gunzip with as many file names as can fit on the command line.